# Default sync folder doesn't work after vagrant up, but does after vagrant reload

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a Virtualbox-managed VM that I am building up, intending to use as a node with Cassandra/OpsCenter.

In the process of setting it up, I noticed that the sync folders are not mounting properly on `vagrant up`. By this, I mean that the I get a permissions error when I try to `touch /vagrant/foo.txt` from inside the VM once it is up. And, if I create a file in my project directory on my host machine, it does not show up in `/vagrant` on the guest VM.

I'm not setting up a sync folder in my Vagrantfile, just using the default behavior. But when I `vagrant reload`, all of a sudden the sync folder works as intended once I SSH back into the VM.

I get no errors in the logs of either the `vagrant up` or the `vagrant reload`.

After reading some other SO posts, I ran both `vagrant up --debug` and `vagrant reload --debug` and pulled out all output I could find related to `mount` operations.

Vagrantfile, provisioning code, and selected logs are pasted below. Any idea what gives here? TIA.

I'm using Virtualbox 4.3.12 r93733, Vagrant 1.6.3, [Hahsicorp Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit VM](https://vagrantcloud.com/hashicorp/precise64), running on OSX Mavericks 10.9.4.

---

#### Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4568, guest: 80
end
```

#### Bootstrap.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get install -y python-software-properties
add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
add-apt-repository -y ppa:cassou/emacs
apt-get update
apt-get -y install curl

# install emacs
echo 'INSTALLING EMACS'
apt-get --yes --force-yes install emacs24 emacs24-el emacs24-common-non-dfsg

# install jvm / oracle jdk
# see: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get
echo 'INSTALLING JAVA'
apt-get -y install default-jre

echo 'INSTALLING ORACLE JDK'
echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | sudo debconf-set-selections
apt-get --yes --force-yes install oracle-java7-installer

# install cassandra
echo 'INSTALLING CASSANDRA'
echo "deb http://debian.datastax.com/community stable main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
curl -L http://debian.datastax.com/debian/repo_key | apt-key add -
apt-get update
apt-get -y install dsc20
service cassandra stop
rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/*

# install ops center
echo 'INSTALLING OPS CENTER'
echo "deb http://debian.datastax.com/community stable main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/datastax.community.list
apt-get update
apt-get -y install opscenter
service opscenterd start

# reboot the machine
reboot
```

#### Extracted logs

```
INITIAL DEBUG STATEMENTS (starting at line ~2701)
INFO synced_folders: Invoking synced folder enable: virtualbox
 INFO interface: output: Mounting shared folders...
 INFO interface: output: ==> default: Mounting shared folders...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
 INFO interface: detail: /vagrant => /Users/andrew/projects/tutorials/vagrant_cassandra
 INFO interface: detail:     default: /vagrant => /Users/andrew/projects/tutorials/vagrant_cassandra
    default: /vagrant => /Users/andrew/projects/tutorials/vagrant_cassandra
...line 2997
DEBUG guest: Searching for cap: mount_virtualbox_shared_folder
DEBUG guest: Checking in: ubuntu
DEBUG guest: Checking in: debian
DEBUG guest: Checking in: linux
DEBUG guest: Found cap: mount_virtualbox_shared_folder in linux
 INFO guest: Execute capability: mount_virtualbox_shared_folder [#<Vagrant::Machine: default (VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Provider)>, "vagrant", "/vagrant", {:guestpath=>"/vagrant", :hostpath=>"/Users/andrew/projects/tutorials/vagrant_cassandra", :disabled=>false, :owner=>"vagrant", :group=>"vagrant"}] (ubuntu)
DEBUG ssh: Checking whether SSH is ready...
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: SSH is ready!
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute:  (sudo=false)
DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 0
...line 3026
INFO ssh: Execute: mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` vagrant /vagrant (sudo=true)
DEBUG ssh: stderr: stdin: is not a tty

DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 0
...line 3039
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute: /sbin/initctl emit --no-wait vagrant-mounted MOUNTPOINT=/vagrant (sudo=true)
DEBUG ssh: stderr: stdin: is not a tty

DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 0
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::SyncedFolders:0x0000010122eeb0>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::SyncedFolderCleanup:0x000001030d91f8>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::SyncedFolderNFS::ActionCleanup:0x00000103091998>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::PrepareNFSValidIds:0x0000010303e518>
...line
#################
### AT THIS POINT, MY PROJECT ROOT DIR HAS NOT BEEN MOUNTED TO /vagrant, AS IT IS EMPTY
vagrant@precise64:~$ ls /vagrant/

vagrant@precise64:~$

### THEN RAN A RELOAD --DEBUG, WHICH MAKES THE MOUNTED DIRECTORY WORK...
~/projects/tutorials/vagrant_cassandra(master) $ vagrant reload --debug
... line 26309
INFO interface: output: Mounting shared folders...
 INFO interface: output: ==> default: Mounting shared folders...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
 INFO interface: detail: /vagrant => /Users/andrew/projects/tutorials/vagrant_cassandra
 INFO interface: detail:     default: /vagrant => /Users/andrew/projects/tutorials/vagrant_cassandra
    default: /vagrant => /Users/andrew/projects/tutorials/vagrant_cassandra
...line 26573
DEBUG guest: Searching for cap: mount_virtualbox_shared_folder
DEBUG guest: Checking in: ubuntu
DEBUG guest: Checking in: debian
DEBUG guest: Checking in: linux
DEBUG guest: Found cap: mount_virtualbox_shared_folder in linux
 INFO guest: Execute capability: mount_virtualbox_shared_folder [#<Vagrant::Machine: default (VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Provider)>, "vagrant", "/vagrant", {:guestpath=>"/vagrant", :hostpath=>"/Users/andrew/projects/tutorials/vagrant_cassandra", :disabled=>false, :owner=>"vagrant", :group=>"vagrant"}] (ubuntu)
DEBUG ssh: Checking whether SSH is ready...
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: SSH is ready!
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute:  (sudo=false)
DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 0
...line 26601
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute: mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` vagrant /vagrant (sudo=true)
DEBUG ssh: stderr: stdin: is not a tty
DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 0
...line 26615
DEBUG ssh: Re-using SSH connection.
 INFO ssh: Execute: /sbin/initctl emit --no-wait vagrant-mounted MOUNTPOINT=/vagrant (sudo=true)
DEBUG ssh: stderr: stdin: is not a tty

DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 0
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::SyncedFolders:0x000001014f48e8>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::SyncedFolderCleanup:0x0000010142caf0>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::SyncedFolderNFS::ActionCleanup:0x00000101367430>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::ProviderVirtualBox::Action::PrepareNFSValidIds:0x000001012c5d60>

### NOW MY PROJECT DIR HAS BEEN SUCCESSFULLY MOUNTED TO /vagrant
vagrant@precise64:~$ ls /vagrant/
bootstrap.sh  Vagrantfile
vagrant@precise64:~$
```

Comment: I suspect that there's some incompatibility between the GuestAdditions that are installed on your Vagrant Box and your VirtualBox. Another possible reason is that something in your provision process breaks  GuestAdditions.
I suggest you to check few things:
1) Try running the machine without any provisioning - do you still have the problem?
2) Try adding to your provision the following: `/etc/init.d/vboxadd setup` and check if it helps

I think that Vagrant recompiles the GuestAdditions kernel modules on `reload` and that's the reason your problem is being fixed.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/355) bug report for more info as well.

Comment: @MichaelS you're right, there is some incompatibility. I just noticed a vagrant message saying that guest additions version didn't match vagrant version. That said, I think the root of the error was the reboot (as noted in accepted answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the `reboot` command at the end of your provisioning script. I did several test runs while commenting out your provisioning script step, and it always worked correctly. With the provisioning script it would fail as you noted. After removing the `reboot` at the end, the shared folder mounting always seems to work.

I found this blog post which may shed more light: [How to Reboot a Vagrant Guest VM During Provisioning](https://www.exratione.com/2014/06/how-to-reboot-a-vagrant-guest-vm-during-provisioning/). They describe the need to remount the shared folder after doing a reboot.

I'm not sure you even need a reboot. Neither Cassandra nor OpsCenter will require it, and I think your provisioning setup will work fine.

Another optimization you could make is to reduce the number of `apt-get update` calls. Those can be pretty slow depending on network connection speed. For example you could move the `debian.datastax.com` config steps to the top, call `apt-get update` once, then do all your installs.